# How do I import a Java package in Scala?

Tags: scala, import, package

I have created a jar-file with a compiled Java class. Now I want to import it in Scala. But it doesn't work.

The package name is `se.mydomain.testproj` and here is a small Scala application:

```
object TestCrypt {

    import se.mydomain.testproj._

    def main(args: Array[String]) {
      println("Hello")
    }
}
```

I use Eclipse and have added the jar file to the Build Path.

In Eclipse, I get the error: `not found: value se`

How can I import Java classes from a Jar file in Scala?

Comment: I'm not sure Scala allows `import` statement inside of `object`, try moving it at the top of a file (after `package ...`, but before `object ...`)

Comment: Apparently, the jar file is not in the path or its name is different.

Comment: Use a package and try without Eclipse (using javac and scalac). Sometimes the IDE is the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do this all the time in Eclipse, so it definitely works.  Do you see the jar in the Referenced Libraries of the project?  Do you have the package name right?

Also, an import in the object as opposed to the top of the file should be fine.

Comment: Yes, the jar file is in the Referenced Libraries.

Comment: And the package name matches exactly?  What if you pick out just one class and import it as opposed to using the underscore syntax?  Does it work?